# How to download a copy of the CiviCRM User and Administrator Guide?

Tags: documentation

I am a new admin user of CiviCRM and want to know how to download a copy of the latest [Admin Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/) rather than view online? This is referred to in the introduction and refers to the chapter 'History of this Guide' but I can't find a link to a file anywhere.

Comment: What is the preferred format for your local guide. You can find the markdown source of the documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide) but I suppose that is not convenient.

Answer (score 3):

What follows are steps to download and view the User Guide offline using the MkDocs software.

*Caveats: this solution (a) requires some technical skill to set up, and (b) still requires a web browser to read (though not an Internet connection).*

1. Install [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (python package manager)

   - OS X: `brew install python`
   - Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install python-pip python-wheel`
2. Install [MkDocs](http://mkdocs.org/)

   ```
   sudo pip install mkdocs
   ```
3. Download the source files for the guide from GitHub.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide.git
   cd civicrm-user-guide
   ```
4. Run MkDocs

   ```
   mkdocs serve
   ```
5. View through your browser at http://localhost:8000

More information about the process is available on the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/documentation/) page within the CiviCRM Developer Guide.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you can get a download version of the Admin Guide other than to Copy and Paste.

On the CiviCRM Documentation wiki page at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+Documentation, in the bottom left hand corner, there is reference to some CiviCRM books that are available for purchase.  I believe that if you use a discount code PACKT20, you can get a 20% discount but I haven't personally tested this out.

Hope this helps.